# FCM push notification : java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, weblogic, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm trying to implement send Push notification on Android device using FCM in Java but i'm getting this error :

```
 java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.readv0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.readv(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:440)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOInputStream.readInternal(NIOSocketMuxer.java:803)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOInputStream.read(NIOSocketMuxer.java:745)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOInputStream.read(NIOSocketMuxer.java:728)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.readFromNetwork(JSSEFilterImpl.java:462)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.handleUnwrapResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:634)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:515)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:96)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:219)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.getHttpClient(HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:711)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1444)
    at utils.FCM.send_FCM_Notification(FCM.java:71)
    at Services.CreateMeeting.call(CreateMeeting.java:283)
    at Services.CreateMeeting.doPost(CreateMeeting.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at filter.Loginfilter.doFilter(Loginfilter.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

My Class of FCM is :

```
public class FCM 
{
    final static private String FCM_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String tokenId= "fh11LQ1st3M:APA91bEz1VjEKNiM9YZBzTF8SbW1esE8ykYvfSpBMDfhCNgcvdDHTbe_iTLd_golWi0PGH0vs630bXlWKT9Tw3oZTp6YOooYXfx3GkFCK7k21sNcV4emaO6sImmCBuSkMk1EyjVE2Ndi";
        send_FCM_Notification(tokenId, "New Notificationcreated","Create Meeting");
    }

    public static void send_FCM_Notification(String tokenId, String message, String type)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(FCM_URL);

            HttpURLConnection conn;

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key=AAAAVX9r9wY:APA91bEi2GgGrbF_XxJ9fAsdGF07kE8wSHU7KOYPOVMvEXaFaFJDisO18r086i-Ju7Gllv0abOz7SsAgL3RdR-Vq8CMZdR7HsBnDjVrmyZ-u2aeeLdnf-ZFxSB7V_NzkMeMK4d7S87ml");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

            JSONObject typejson = new JSONObject();
            typejson.put("title","Demo");
            typejson.put("body", message);
            typejson.put("message", message);
            typejson.put("type", type);
            typejson.put("timestamp", new Date());
            typejson.put("priority", 1);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("to",tokenId.trim());
            json.put("data", typejson);
            System.out.println(json);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(json.toString());
            wr.flush();

            int status = 0;

            if( null != conn )
            {
                status = conn.getResponseCode();
            }

            if( status != 0)
            {
                if( status == 200 )
                {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exception) 
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

> When i call this method ( send_FCM_Notification ) from main method it
>   works but when it gets call from servlet using Weblogic server it
>   throws this error

I'm unable to find out exact cause of this Exception please try to help me

Comment: I can recommend using postman and test the output of the request there. This would help you, locating the error, if it's inside your code or if the API you're trying to reach is not available. "existing connection forcibly closed" this phrase reminds me a bit of a session termination on a router interface like a cisco CLI, that sounds not like being part of your code ... alternatively try using breakpoints to keep track of the state of `conn` during the steps of your program

Comment: I tried with postman also but still i'm getting same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I enabled SSL port in weblogic and try with https url and it Resolve my problem.